# GetDC function in separate thread takes too long to return

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am learning OpenGL and using windows api for windowing. I have a rendering function and at the end it calls `SwapBuffers(deviceContext)`.

At first I used `GetDC()` to obtain the DC handle (like this: `SwapBuffers(GetDC(hWND))`, and it worked smoothly (without releasing it).
When I tried to move the rendering to a separate thread it worked properly for a couple of hundred frames, after `GetDC()` slowed down dramatically, like it took less than 1ms to return and and suddenly over 300ms. This caused decreasing FPS. After I found the root cause I changed to store DC once at the beginning and release on exit, and now it's working.

The question is why `GetDC()` without `ReleaseDC()` slows down so drastic and sudden, when I call it couple of hundred times in a separate thread from window class? It doesn't do in the main thread.

Comment: You should consider retrieving the device context from the thread owning the window, and release it from that thread as well. Assuming proper coordination, you can pass that DC to the rendering thread. All of this is assuming, that you are calling `GetDC`, not `getDC`. I don't know what `getDC` is.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in MSDN documentation:

[GetDC function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> After painting with a common DC, the **`ReleaseDC`** function must be called
>   to release the DC. Class and private DCs do not have to be released.
>   `ReleaseDC` must be called from the **same thread** that called `GetDC`. The
>   number of DCs is limited only by available memory.

Therefore the function should not be used like this: <s>`SwapBuffers(GetDC(hWND))`</s>. Always obtain `HDC` handle and call `ReleaseDC` to avoid resource leak.

The program may work smoothly (at least for a while) but still leak resources, it will eventually crash.

You can monitor GDI leaks in Task Manager. Go to "Processes" tab, select column for "GDI objects".